# can you answer a push notification with your voice?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios7

can you answer a push notification with your voice? So when you iPhone is locked and you get a push notification, can you react to it with you voice?

Comment: Your question is too vague. At least describe a situation or a use case of what you want to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You're not registered for audio push notifications in your app. Just register for it like this in your App Delegate:

```
  - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //Whatever you have already in your app delegate...

    // Let device know you're going to be sending one of these types of notifications.
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
        (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

    return YES;
}
```

The 5 types are:

- UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge
- UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound
- UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert
- UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone
- UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability

Here's the documentation: [Registering for Remote Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIRemoteNotificationType)

also refere this [documents](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1)

Hope that helps!

Comment: @Rushabh... whats the prblm in that answer... ??

Answer (score -1):

You can not play voice in push notification.Push notification Payload not contain your voice.
Users see notifications in the following ways:

- Displaying an alert or banner
- Badging the app’s icon
- Playing a sound.

According to apple push notification document
[image]